# Is it possible to use ARReferenceImage objects created programatically from the images on iOS 11.3.1

Tags: swift, ios11, arkit

I recently replaced a heavy OpenCV with the native ARKit for image detection and tracking. The images that I want to track downloaded from the web service and stored locally. I'm creating the `ARImageReference` objects from them using the following code:

```
guard
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageLocalPath),
    let cgImage = image.cgImage
else {
    return nil
}

return ARReferenceImage(cgImage, orientation: .up, physicalWidth: 0.12)
```

The width is small, because the images are not so big as well, around 180 x 240 pixels each, but the printed ones may be bigger.

The session configured depending on the current iOS version since `ARImageTrackingConfiguration` not available for iOS 11:

```
private lazy var configuration: ARConfiguration = {
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *),
        ARImageTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
        return ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
    }

    return ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
}()

if #available(iOS 12.0, *),
    let imagesTrackingConfig = configuration as? ARImageTrackingConfiguration {
    imagesTrackingConfig.trackingImages = referenceImages
} else if let worldTrackingConfig = configuration as? ARWorldTrackingConfiguration {
    worldTrackingConfig.detectionImages = referenceImages
}

session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

The code above works great for iOS versions 12 and 13 even if I use `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration`. Images correctly detected by the ARKit. But when I try to run it on iOS 11.3.1, the app immediately crashes with the following error:

> Assert:
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleCV3D/AppleCV3D-1.13.11/library/VIO/OdometryEngine/src/FrameDownsampleNode/FrameDownsampler.cpp,
>   62: std::abs(static_cast(aspect_1) -
>   static_cast(src_frame.image.width * output_frame_height_)) <
>   max_slack (lldb)

Is it possible that the dynamic markers creation programmatically is not available for the iOS version below 12.0 or am I doing something wrong? Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any information regarding the specific versions. Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some time, I finally managed to find a source of the issue, so I'm posting it here since it may be useful for someone else with the same problem.

The answer is **YES**, it's possible to create `ARReferenceImage` objects programmatically, and use them on iOS 11.3.1 for image detection.

My problem was in the source images itself, and it looks like the improper scale of the `CGImage` was causing the crash. Downloaded from the API images are 180x240. By checking the sizes of the `CGImage` which used for the creation of the `ARReferenceImage` I realized that they're not scaled properly, so the `CGImage` size was the same as the source `UIImage`.

I decided to try to re-draw the images using the following:

```
func getRedrawnCgImage(_ originalImage: UIImage) -> CGImage? {
    guard let cgImage = originalImage.cgImage else { return nil }

    let size = CGSize(width: cgImage.width, height: cgImage.height)
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    originalImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    let redrawnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return redrawnImage?.cgImage
}
```

The result `CGImage` has the size 540x720, so with x3 scale of the original size as it should be. By using those redrawn images, I got rid of the crash, but this is rather a workaround than the proper solution for now.